# 2 rows having equal heights to fill parent element with Susy

Tags: susy-compass, susy

Not sure if this is something Susy is made to handle, how can I get 2 elements that include a `span` to fill the parent evenly? So row 1 and 2 will have equal heights.

```
              --------------
              .  row 1     .
  container   .------------.
              .  row 2     .
              --------------
```

eg css

```
.row-1 {
  @include span(5 of 12)
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think suzy is geared to control the height of elements, why don't you just use height: 50% on the rows 1 and 2?